# Modify A Jquery to accept multiple queries instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, ajax

Currently in my system I have the ability to select an option from a drop down box, this option then displays input boxes which the user can enter/select information from. This information is then sent to the database and information is returned. I need to modify this so that instead of the drop down box, 3 or 4 of these options are displayed on one page, one button is pressed and if any of the options are selected, each individual query is sent to the database. For instance if they select Sex M/F and Subscribed Y/N 2 separate queries are sent and returned.

Here is example text of what I currently have - This works perfectly well;

Java Script;

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }

$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); } 
});

$(document).ready(function() {
// Variable to hold request
var request;

$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: '300px'});

//$("#distance_slider").slider({});

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#criteria").submit(function(event){

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    //$("#isajax").val("1");    

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
          url: "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record={RECORD_VALUE}&first_run=1&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        //console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        //console.log(response);
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

HTML - Missing ending for tables just a snippet of code

```
<form id="criteria" name="criteria">

<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" name="criteria_search">
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" width="75%" align="left"><strong>Add Rule : &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                        <select name="rule" id="rule" onChange="toggletdDisplay(this.form);"> 

                        <option value="email">Email</option>
                    <option value="sex">Sex</option>
                    <option value="account">Account</option>
                    <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right" name="buttonForm" id="buttonForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="PopupContactsCriteria"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="query" value="true"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="record" value="{RECORD_VALUE}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="{MODULE_NAME}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="{FORM_SUBMIT}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="sugar_body_only" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="{FORM}" />          
                    <input class="button" type="submit" name="addButton" id="addButton" value="  Add Selected  " disabled/>
                </td>   
                <td class="dataLabel" name="instructions" id="instructions" style="display: inline;padding: 50px;"> <p style="color:black;font-size:10px;"><br /> <i> </i> </td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" >Email Address Required?  Yes <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED}>  No <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}></td>
                </tr>

            <td class="dataLabel" name="sex" id="sex" style="display: none;" > <br /> Male  <input type="radio" name="sex_c" value="Male" {SEX_M_CHECKED}>  Female  <input type="radio" name="sex_c" value="Female" {SEX_F_CHECKED}></td>

            <td class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" style="display: none;" >  <p><Strong>Email Address (Please additionally select Assigned Racecourse)</strong><p/>Has email address <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED}>  <br /> No email address  <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}></td>

            <td class="dataLabel" name="account" id="account" style="display: none;" >  <br />Has Account  <input type="radio" name="account_c" value="True" {ACCOUNT_T_CHECKED}>  No Account <input type="radio" name="account_c" value="False" {ACCOUNT_F_CHECKED}></td>

            <td class="dataLabel" name="awc" id="awc" style="display: none;" >  <br />AWC Newsletter Selected <input type="radio" name="awc_c" value="True"> AWC Newsletter Not Selected <input type="radio" name="awc_c" value="False"></td>
```

Here is what I am trying to make work - I don't know how to edit the Jquery to accept multiple inputs, or to iterate through queries and show them the same way

New Script using ArrayList

```
// Bind to the submit event of our form

$("#additional_criteria").submit(function(event){

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    //$("#isajax").val("1");    

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
          url: "index.php?module=Prospects&action=PopupContactsCriteria&html=Popup_Contacts_Criteria_picker&form=ContactsForm&record={RECORD_VALUE}&first_run=1&form_submit=true&query=true&sugar_body_only=1",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        //console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        //console.log(response);
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show Additional Rules (*Not Required)</button>

<div id="myDIV" hidden="true">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="edit view">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="additional_criteria" name="additional_criteria">

                <table width="100%" border="0" name="additional_criteria">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p><Strong> Additional Rules</strong><p/></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" name="email" id="email" >Email Address Required?  Yes <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="true_ex" {EMAIL_TEX_CHECKED}>  No <input type="radio" name="email_c" value="false" {EMAIL_F_CHECKED}></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabe" name="account" id="account" > Has Account  <input type="radio" name="account_c" value="True" {ACCOUNT_T_CHECKED}>  No Account <input type="radio" name="account_c" value="False" {ACCOUNT_F_CHECKED}></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" name="awc" id="awc" >  AWC Newsletter Selected <input type="radio" name="awc_c" value="True"> AWC Newsletter Not Selected <input type="radio" name="awc_c" value="False"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dataLabel" name="mobile" id="mobile"  >  Has mobile  <input type="radio" name="mobile_c" value="True" {MOBILE_T_CHECKED}>  No mobile <input type="radio" name="mobile_c" value="False" {MOBILE_F_CHECKED}></td>
                </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" name="buttonForm" id="buttonForm">
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="PopupContactsCriteria"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="query" value="true"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="record" value="{RECORD_VALUE}"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="module" value="{MODULE_NAME}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="{FORM_SUBMIT}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="sugar_body_only" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="form" value="{FORM}" />          
                            <input class="button" type="submit" name="addAdditionalButton" id="addAdditionalButton" value="  Add Additional  " />
                        </td>   
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit, instead of `.serialize()`, use [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). This will generate an array of objects, each object containing one input and its value from your form :

```
[
  {
    name: "action",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "query",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "record",
    value: "3"
  }
]
```

Then it gets very easy to make one request per field :

```
for(let oneObject of serializedData){
    $.post({
        url: "index.php",
        data: oneObject
    })
}
```

This will make three different (and parallel) calls, the first one one carrying `{name: "action", value: "1"}`, the second one `{name: "query", value: "2"}`, etc.

Comment: i have updated my initial question with this, it shows a loading icon then doesn't return any values from the query. However the same query on the first method does return. Any idea why?

Comment: Well there's some server-side diagnostic to do then. What does your server say? I have no way to know why it's not responding.